# Accessing tables from 2 different server in a single query in python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I tried to create a table from 2 tables of different server.
I am really stuck on how to establish the connection to 2 servers in a single SQL query.
If anyone know how to do this, please help.

I have given a sample example of what I want.
The below is the query that I need to execute:

```
(SELECT A.period AS period,c.date AS date,b.time as time
FROM ABC.PERIOD_DATE a, 
    DEF.DATE_WEEK b,
    DEF.TIME_WEEK c
)
```

Below are the credentials that is needed to connect to the server:

```
where the table PERIOD_DATE is from "MYPERIOD" server , where schema=ABC,
user='abc_999',password='abc_999', host name ='abc.999.org',port = 9999
```

```
DATE_TIME and TIME_WEEK is from "MYDATETIME" server , where schema=DEF,
user='def_111',password='def_111', host name ='def.111.org',port = 1111
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you create Link Server?

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.